# Не устанавливается текст в JTextField при клике на JButton

Tags: java, swing, button

Когда кликаю на кнопку, текст не выводится в `JTextField`.
И даже простые `System.out.prntln("..");` не выводятся в консоли.

Код для кнопки был сгенирирован самостоятельно:

```
jButton1.setText("нажимай");
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
```

Сам метод обработки:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    for (Person h : people) {   
        jLabel3.setText(String.valueOf(h.toString()));
        System.out.println("Clicked:");
        System.out.println(h.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Так, может, просто коллекция (или массив) `people` пуста?

Comment: Да. просто в драйвер классе без swing работало все а сейчас дейстительно посуто

Comment: Если в `person` 0 элементов, то неудивительно, что ничего не выводится на экран и никакой текст не устанавливается в `jLabel3`.. И в любом случае очень странно устанавливать текст для всех элементов коллекции по очереди. С таким же успехом можно просто установить текст из последнего элемента. А ещё конструкция `String.valueOf(h.toString())` избыточна: если `h` не может быть `null`, то достаточно использовать только `h.toString()`. В противном случае - только `String.valueOf(h)`.

Comment: Спасибо, все учту!